# Cross join left join count row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have these tables:

**Task Group table**

`id       name
 1        cooking
 2        baking`

**Task Status table**

`id       name
 1        open
 2        done?
 3        completed
 4        re-open
 5        suspend`

**Tasks table**

`project_id   task_group_id   task_status_id   task_name
 1             1               1               cooking martabak
 1             1               2               cooking sate kambing
 1             1               3               cooking nasi uduk
 1             1               4               cooking nasi goreng
 1             1               1               cooking martabak telor
 1             1               2               cooking sate ayam
 1             1               5               cooking nasi tutug oncom
 1             1               5               cooking nasi pera
 1             2               1               bake nastar
 1             2               2               bake bolu pisang
 1             2               3               bake bika ambon
 1             2               5               bake bolu kukus
 1             2               3               bake cheese stik
 1             2               1               bake bolu ketan
 1             2               5               bake papais
 1             2               1               bake boled`

and the result that what i want is like this:

`project      task_group       task_status      number
 Restaurant   Cooking          Completed        1
 Restaurant   Cooking          Done?            2
 Restaurant   Cooking          Open             2
 Restaurant   Cooking          Re-open          1
 Restaurant   Baking           Completed        2
 Restaurant   Baking           Done?            1
 Restaurant   Baking           Open             3
 Restaurant   Baking           Re-open          0`

**task status "suspend" is excluded**

i have tried to cross join tasks table with task status table using subquery with where clause task_status.name in ('open', 'done?', 'completed', 're-open'), but i can't get the right count aggregation

Comment: just need to group by first table name and second table name

Comment: i have tried it, but the count result is not right... i am sure i miss the link on join, but i don't know how i join it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    project.name AS project,
    Task_Group.name as task_group ,
    Task_Status.name as task_status,
    COUNT(*) AS number
FROM
    Tasks
    JOIN Task_Group
        ON Tasks.task_group_id = Task_Group.id
    JOIN Task_Status
        ON Task.task_status_id=Task_Status.id
    JOIN project_table
        ON Task.project_id=project_table.project_id
WHERE 
    Task_Status.Id IN(1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY
    project_table.name,
    Task_Group.name,
    Task_Status.name
```

Comment: i can't get the re-open status count, i want to show the listed task status as above even if it has no row in table